# I don't want to display a message using the Toast class

Tags: java

I made an application to find the key using coordinates. Everything seems to be working, but the notification of the location does not come. I made the notification using the Toast class.
Here is the code:
MainActivity:

```
    private TextView coordinatesOut;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private String sDown;
    private String sMove;
    private String sUp;

    private final float xKey = 568;
    private final float yKey = 150;
    private final float deltaKey = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinatesOut = findViewById(R.id.coordinatesOut);

        coordinatesOut.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            x = motionEvent.getX();
            y = motionEvent.getY();

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    sDown = "Нажатие: координата X = " + x + ", координата y = " + y;
                    sMove = "";
                    sUp = "";
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    sMove = "Движение: координата X = " + x + ", координата y = " + y;
                    if (x < (xKey + deltaKey) && x > (xKey - deltaKey) && y < (yKey + deltaKey) && y > (yKey - deltaKey)) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.successful_search_One, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    sMove = "";
                    sUp = "Отпускание: координата X = " + x + ", координата y = " + y;
                    break;
            }

            coordinatesOut.setText(sDown + "\n" + sMove + "\n" + sUp);

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

I don't know what to say here. I tried to figure it out somehow, but I never figured it out.